# How to create volume mapping between a remote SSH server's directory path and dir of CF app (using SSHFS)

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have to create a Cloud Foundry application (on bluemix) which needs to perform storing the generated data in a directory. I am planning to use the SSHFS, where I can configure my app to use a remote SSH server for storing the data. I have understood this way of storing data is similar to the shared volume mounted.

I found an [article](https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-cloud-foundry/products/getting-started-with-wordpress-on-cloud-foundry) on how to perform the same, but the article doesn't have information on the volume mapping. i.e. It shows the path to be used on the remote SSH server, but I don't know how to map the same to the application's directory (say /data within the cf application)

Can someone help me on how to set the mapping between the remote SSH directory path to the app path, from which app instances reads or writes data?

Answer (score -1):

Storing user data through a file system mount [is not possible, or recommended, for Cloud Foundry applications](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#filesystem). Developers do not have access to the server environment to configure the host system.

Application data should be stored in a [connected service backend](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/), like a database or object storage.

IBM Bluemix provides [numerous services for data storage](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/), including relational databases, non-relational databases and object storage.

The [object storage service](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/object-storage/) would be a sensible approach for the use case outlined above.

Comment: Our app has been created in such a way that it uses a shared directory from which other app instances read or write data. I think cf wordpress article that i shared shows such an approach using cflinuxfs2, where the app manifest is modified to add the SSH server details (key, dir etc). Thanks for your Response, James.

Comment: It might be much easier to deploy your application to IBM Containers using Docker and have a shared filesystem mount through their volume storage. This should work without having to use the steps you mentioned to hack around with buildpacks.